# Primary and secondary font with Chakra UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fonts, styling, chakra-ui

I am using Chakra Ui with React and I am trying to use two different fonts for two components, I already imported them using the Global method described in the docs but how can I use only the secondary one in my current component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you mean secondary one, I am assuming that this is your secondary font? If so, there are two things you should be aware of. It is the `textStyles` key and `extendTheme` function from Chakra UI:

1. Import the `extendTheme` function imported from Chakra UI.

   ```
   import { extendTheme } from "@chakra-ui/react"
   ```
2. Using the extendTheme function will allow you to add new styles. This is where you will place the *textStyles* key:

   ```
   const themeExample = extendTheme({
       // Whatever you pass here will be ADDED to the theme.
       textStyles: { 
           primary: {
               fontFamily: "Font Primary"
           },
           secondary: {
               fontFamily: "Font Secondary"
           },
       },
   });
   ```
3. Now the desired fonts are set up, they are easily accessible:

   ```
   <Box textStyle='primary'>Component One</Box>
   <Box textStyle='secondary'>Component Two</Box>
   ```

More information can be found here: https://chakra-ui.com/docs/features/text-and-layer-styles

Comment: Thank you! I used fontFamily='Secondary Font Name' on the element that I wanted the font applied to but this is better.